# Python Pyglet Window Force Close

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm working on a pyglet application in Python. It is a graphics module, and I'm using it to build a chess game. I've finished the code but I can't seem to close the pyglet window. My intention was to have the window be closed when a king was killed. I tried window.exit(). "window" is my pyglet window object. I'm not sure where else to go. My code is several thousand lines so posting it here wouldn't prove useful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@Attila_Toth answer should work, but I'll add on it and create a custom `pyglet.app.run()` loop within the `pyglet.window.Window` class:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(main, self).__init__(800, 800, fullscreen = False)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        #self.bg = Spr('background.jpg')

        self.alive = 1


    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        #self.bg.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

This example will let you close your window when pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> or when you press the close button in your window manager.

Answer (score 1):

window.exit() function does not exists in pyglet, instead try window.close().
You can call the exit function on the app: as pyglet.app.run() and pyglet.app.exit()

```
from pyglet.gl import *

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [-0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.0,0.5,0.0]),
                                                       ('c3B', [100,200,220, 200,110,100, 100,250,100]))

class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400, 300)
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 1.0)

        self.triangle = Triangle()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.triangle.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    def exit_callback(self, dt):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow(400, 400, "My Pyglet Window", resizable=True)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_once(window.exit_callback , 2) 
    pyglet.app.run()
```

The code above will close the window after 2 seconds.